# Does BeginRequest fire everytime? Which HttpApplication events fire when? Is it different for Ajax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, page-lifecycle, ihttpmodule, httpapplication

I am a little confused about the HttpApplication events.

I have a SessionService* that is initialized from an HttpModule.  The `HttpModule` subscribes to `HttpApplication.BeginRequest`.

In the module I create a `new SessionService()`.

The constructor of the SessionService sets`SessionService.ServiceId = Guid.NewGuid()`.

I am using jquery to send two ajax requests from a link being clicked on a webpage.  Both of the links return JSON indicating the `SessionService.ServiceId`, and it is **the same**.

I don't know why this is happening, but my best guest is I am misunderstanding when the events fire, and that some of them don't fire every httprequest.  Thanks for your help.

*the session service has nothing to do with the HttpSessionState object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BeginRequest` fires on every request: whether it's Ajax or not, it's still a HTTP request.

Be careful: `new Guid()` represents an all-zero GUID. You probably wanted to use `Guid.NewGuid()`.

Comment: That was actually a typo.  The line in the code said Guid.NewGuid().  I rewrote it wrong in the post, but thank you I fixed it.